# AngularJS ng-watch event firing after debounce

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a requirement where I need to show the `typing started and stopped` to the user.

So, I've written a `ng-keyup` for detecting the typing started and have written `ng-model-options="{debounce:800}"` for detecting the typing stopped.

But the problem is `ng-keyup` is not firing for the first time.

So, I thought of writing a watch expression for the model for detecting the text change instead of `ng-keyup`.

Now, the problem is the watch expression is getting fired after the debounce event.so, the typing is showing after the typing gets stopped.

My Code:

```html
<textarea type="text" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type your message..." ng-enter="SendMessage()" ng-model="txtmessage" ng-change="TypingStopped()" ng-model-options="{debounce:800}" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
```

Can anyone suggest me a better option to get the typing functionality?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

keyup will not respond for first entry
use ng-keydown

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash.debounce and scope.$apply for this.
If you are doing this a lot i would recommend custom directive.
I made example with and without use of custom directive.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function ($scope) {
  this.msg = '';
  
  this.onStart = () => {
    this.msg = 'started';
  };
  
  this.onStop = _.debounce(() => {
    $scope.$apply(() => this.msg = 'stoped');
  }, 1000);
});

angular.module('app').directive('onStart', () => ({
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    onStart: '&',
    onStop: '&'
  },
  link: (scope, element) => {
    let isStarted = false;
  
    element.on('keyup', () => {
      scope.$apply(() => {
        if (!isStarted) {
          isStarted = true;
          scope.onStart();
        }
      });
    });

    element.on('keydown', _.debounce(() => {
      scope.$apply(() => {
        isStarted = false;
        scope.onStop();
      });
    }, 800));
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Ex">
  <input type="text" ng-keyup="Ex.onStart()" ng-keydown="Ex.onStop()"><br>
  {{Ex.msg}}<br>
  
  <input type="text" on-start="text = 'started'" on-stop="text = 'stoped'"><br>
  {{text}}                                                                       
</div>
```

If you don't want to add lodash to you project take a look at this debounce implmentation: https://github.com/component/debounce/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Hello @sielakos, I understand this code is correct and working. but I don't know why I'm getting syntax errors in my visual studio. I'm getting an error at this part `=>`.

Comment: My Code is usually this way. 
`plusapp.directive('scrolly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var raw = element[0];
            element.bind('scroll', function () {
                if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.scrolly);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});`

Comment: This is es6 standard. You can either configure your ide to allow it or use es5 standard. Replace arrow functions with function (){}.bind(this); when needed. just read abiut arrow functions in es6 for more info. It would be too much explain in comments.